# How to validate uploaded file size in FileFields in Silverstripe User Forms module

Tags: php, silverstripe

We have a Silverstripe website where the admins can create online forms using the [userform module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/).

To allow a file to be uploaded via the form the admin add a "File Upload Field" to the form. This adds a [Filefield](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FileField.html) to the form.

The Filefield is a simplified version of [UploadField](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/) which allows a number of validation options, including maximum upload file size.

Do these options exist for Filefield?

My issue is I need to keep the global PHP `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` high for backend CMS functionality but I want to limit the front end Filefield uploads to 8meg.

Is it possible to validate Filefield in the userform module so it fails/ displays a message if the file is over a certain size that is small than the PHP variables?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there's built in functionality for it. The documentation states  the file size is limited by the webserver [[1](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/blob/master/docs/en/user-documentation.md#file-upload-field)].

However, `FileField` uses the `Upload` class' `validate()` function which in its turn uses the `Upload_Validator` class' `validate()` function [[2](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/master/filesystem/Upload.php#L536)] which checks for a max file size in the `Config`.

This means you can add the following to your config file to restrict file size:

```
# Don't forget to flush afterwards :-)
Upload_Validator:
  default_max_file_size: '1m' # 1 megabyte
```

Please take note that this is a default setting, which means it probably affects all other `UploadField`s as well. You can however set a limit on the other `UploadField`s that need to handle larger files.

[1] https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/blob/master/docs/en/user-documentation.md#file-upload-field

[2] https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/master/filesystem/Upload.php#L536

Comment: I'd tried the Upload_Validator yml config before and it didn't work - the form submitted normally but the over-sized files don't show up in the form submissions in the CMS.